# Router not navigating to next page but url changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 3 pages in my react application. A login page, a homepage and a video page.

Problem: When the login button is clicked,  it makes POST request successfully but doesn't navigate to next page. When clicked on login button, the url changes to required route but view doesn't change.

Tried: 1) I tried using these two things : this.context.router.push('/app') but it gives me the error saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
2) I tried using browserHistory.push('/app') but that changes the url and and not the view.

```
function getRoutes(store) {

    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
            <Route path='app' component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                <Route>
                    <Route path='/video-screen' component={VideoScreen}/>
                    <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
}
export default getRoutes;
```

Below is my index.js file which is entry point rendering Root using above routes.

```
window.Promise = Promise;
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
injectTapEventPlugin();

var browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    queryKey: false,
    basename: '/'
});

var initialState = window.INITIAL_STATE || {};

var store   = configureStore(initialState, browserHistory);
var routes  = getRoutes(store);
var history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: (state) => state.router
});

const ROOT_CONTAINER = document.getElementById('root');
const onRenderComplete = ()=> {
    console.timeEnd('render');
}

if ( __DEV__ ){
    window._STORE = store;
    window.React = React;
    window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
}
window.localStorage.debug = 'tessact:*'
window._History = history

let muiTheme = getMuiTheme(theme);

console.time('render');
match({ history, routes }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
            <Root store={store}>
                <WithStylesContext onInsertCss={styles=> styles._insertCss()}>
                    <Router {...renderProps} />
                </WithStylesContext>
            </Root>
        </MuiThemeProvider>,
        ROOT_CONTAINER,
        onRenderComplete
    )
});
```

This is my login page

```
export default class LogInComponent extends Component {
    handleLoginButtonClick() {
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://trigger-backend.appspot.com/auth/login/",
            "method": "POST",
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            "data": {
                "password": "apurv",
                "username": "Apurv"
            },
            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
               alert("success");
            },
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            alert(response.auth_token);
            console.log('check');
            this.context.router.push('/app')
        });

    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div className="LoginPage">
                <div className="login-page">
                    <div className="form">
                        <form className="login-form">
                            <input id="username" type="username" placeholder="username"/>
                            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                            <p className="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Request Username and Password</a></p>
                        </form>
                        <button onClick={this.handleLoginButtonClick.bind(this)}>login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img className="Logo_Tessact_White" src="./dev/js/images/TESSACT_logo_white.png"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first problem is here**

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      alert(response.auth_token);
      console.log('check');
      this.context.router.push('/app')
});
```

`this` doesn't reference the component anymore, because it is in different scope. Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead in order to reuse the component's scope

```
$.ajax(settings).done((response) => { // arrow function
     alert(response.auth_token);
     console.log('check');
     this.context.router.push('/app')
});
```

> No binding of this
>
> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the context object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.)

Arrow function instead are called with the context in which it is defined (in this case - your component)

**The other problem is here**

```
LogInComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

is missing, please add it.

---

Also, depending on the version of react-router, **you might not be calling the API correctly, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) for more.**

Comment: after removing bind it says  Cannot read property 'context' of null

Comment: which version of react-router do you use?

Comment: then push is the an error  Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: my other pages are using this.context.router.push and it's working perfectly fine for them. Why is it not working for this component/page only

Comment: you were missing ```LogInComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}```, i've edited my asnwer.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: glad to help;-)